# How to resubscribe to an observable on a change event

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my component I am unsubscribing when the page visibility changes so when a user switches tabs they are not consuming my live streaming data. The below is in the function called on the pagevisibility change event, but it is not working on the case the page becomes visible again.

```
if (document.hidden) {
  this.streamService.disconnect();
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  this.timeClock.unsubscribe();
} else {
  this.streamService.initialize();
  this.subscription = this.resubscribe();
  this.timeClock = this.clockResubscribe();

}
```

Comment: the best way to handle this is using `takeUntil` and `repeatWhen` rxjs oprerator which allows to toggle the subscription based on a boolean value e.g `document.hidden`

Comment: `this.subscription.subscribe()` will resubscribe to your service.

Comment: @Niladri I support the `takeUntil` and `repeatWhen` option. Just want to emphasize that they use Observables. Therefore OP could try something like `fromEvent('visibilitychange').map(()=>document.hidden)`, split that into two by `true`/`false`, and then use these threads for `takeUntil` and `repeatWhen`